# API request python with authentification

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm having problems executing an API request with python. [The API documentation](https://espacecollaboratif.ign.fr/gcms/api/doc) states that authentication is done using HTTP basic.

Here is my code :

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

username = 'XXXX'
password = 'XXXX'
basic = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)
url = 'https://espacecollaboratif.ign.fr/gcms/api/reports'

req = requests.get(url, auth=basic, params="departement=65")
contenu = req.json()

print(contenu)
```

And this is what I get :

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='espacecollaboratif.ign.fr', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /gcms/api/reports?departement=65 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000013BA281E8B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Une tentative de connexion a échoué car le parti connecté n’a pas répondu convenablement au-delà d’une certaine durée ou une connexion établie a échoué car l’hôte de connexion n’a pas répondu'))
```

Comment: It's probably not a problem of authentication. Do you have the same error or another one if you remove `auth=basic`. What is the output of `print(req.status_code)`. It can be difficult to help you without account on IGN. (et puis les messages d'erreur en français, je ne suis pas sûr que ça aide les autres personnes...)

Comment: Looks like a connectivity problem. When I tried your code I got a logical 401 : Unauthorized but no ConnectionError. If you try to get a simple page (like google.com), what do you get ?